# x-axis differ in pcolor and plot_date subplots

Tags: matplotlib, axis, subplot

I'd like to create a plot of color-coded data as a subplot using pcolor() and a plot_date() subplot of an other dataset beneath. The period of time is the same, so the ticks have to be straight among each other. But because of the colorbar the width of both x-axis differ. Is there a way to squeeze the plot_date()-axis or another option I didn't notice?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a horizontal colorbar by `pl.colorbar(orientation="horizontal")`. So the width of axes created by pcolor() and plot_date() are the same.